# Past simple Or past Particple?

Tags: tense

Is this sentence correct?

It is not surprising that her death cast a pale of gloom over all those who had come in contact with her.

Is "who had come in contact" right form?
Or can I make this the sentence like below?

It is not surprising that her death cast a pale of gloom over all those who came in contact with her.

Comment: @oerkelens, I think you've got that right on the money. You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: @sraboy If you say so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since she is dead, we would reasonably assume that new people are no longer coming in contact with her.

Therefore, the past perfect (*those who had come*) is appropriate, to indicate that the "coming in contact" happened *and* ended in the past.

The alternative sentence seems to indicate that people who touched her after she died were affected by it.